# Switch statement not working, just goes straight to default

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Hi I am learning javascript and understand the concepts of switch statements having used them in php but for some reason the below just isn't working and i dont get why!  Changed it to an if statement and it works but for this task we have to use switch statement.

```
// function to calculate player rank 
 function calcRank(points){
    let rank = "";
     switch (points){
        case points <1600:
            rank = "no rank";
            break;
        case points <1800:
            rank = "class B";
            break;
        case points <2000:
            rank = "class A";
            break;
        case points <2200:
            rank = "Expert";
            break;
        case points <2400:
            rank = "National Master";
            break;
        case points >= 2400:
            rank = "Senior Master";
            break;
        default:
            rank = "unranked";
     }
     
     return rank;
 }
 
 //function to display rank
 function displayRank(){
     console.log(calcRank(2500));
 }

displayRank();
```

Comment: [DOC](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: `case` has to be followed by a specific value to be compared with `points`, not an expression.

Comment: `case points < 1600:` is equivalent to `if (points == (points < 1600))`

Comment: You're mixing if conditions with switch statement. Check here to see how switch works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: use if else... case is not meant to evaluate expressions.

Comment: thanks guys, i now see my error :)